# Why is Xcode convinced my Desktop is under version control?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, warnings

[image]

`/Users/pcperini/Desktop/.git` and `/Users/pcperini/Desktop/.svn` do not exist.
Where is Xcode getting this from? Can it be fixed?

Comment: How do you know they don't exist? They're hidden files, not shown in Finder by default.

Comment: I `ls -la`'d `/Users/pcperini/Desktop`.

Comment: Then they're really not there. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: needed to remove the repository from the organizer.